# How does Ruby on Rails do this trick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am just beginning to learn Rails. So I created a model Bookmark, opened rails console, and entered this:

> Bookmark.all

Result:

> Bookmark Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "bookmarks".* FROM "bookmarks" 
>   etc.

Then I entered this:

> Bookmark.all.count

Result:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "bookmarks"

The performance gain of this optimization is obvious, so I understand *why* they did it. What I don't understand it is, *how*? I am too new to Ruby to easily search through the source code. If you were to implement this, how would you approach it?

Comment: The short answer is 'magic'!  Rails and the ActiveRecord pattern does a lot to abstract away the database queries.  There is a huge amount of infrastructure built to enable this simpler way of interacting with the database to anwser your question fully here.  You may have more look by googling for ActiveRecord pattern for the philosophical discussion (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how you might defer an action until the data is needed (please note that this is much simpler than ActiveRecord, makes no effort to be efficient, and was simply the quickest way to describe the concept).

First, we have a simple database consisting of the numbers from 1 to 100. This will be our dataset that we query:

```
class Database
  def numbers
    (1..100).to_a
  end
end
```

The Query object will maintain a reference to a database object, plus an array of instructions. Instructions are added to the array using the `where` method.

```
class Query
  attr_accessor :lambdas, :database
  def initialize
    @database = Database.new
    @lambdas = []
  end

  def where(condition)
    lambdas << condition
    # after an instruction is added, return the object to allow more chaining.
    self
  end
end
```

Once the parameters of the query have been established, you still only have a query object that hasn't asked the database for anything, until you call `execute`:

```
class Query
  def execute
    lambdas.inject(database.numbers) do |set, lambda|
      set.select(&lambda)
    end
  end
end

# the set of numbers divisible by 2 and 3:
q = Query.new.where(->(x){ x.even? }).where(->(x){ x % 3 == 0 })
q.execute #=> [6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 66, 72, 78, 84, 90, 96]
```

ActiveRecord does a few nice things for you, including automatic array conversion when necessary. Instead of implementing all of the array/enumerable methods, however, we can simply define a `method_missing` to catch all of the messages that haven't been defined for our Query class. We'll just assume they should be called on an array, which, conveniently enough, is what is returned from `execute`.

```
class Query
  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    execute.send(name, *args, &block)
  end
end
```

So now we can take our query object from before, and interact with it directly as if it were an array:

```
q.map { |n| n * 2 }
#=> [12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96, 108, 120, 132, 144, 156, 168, 180, 192]

q.count #=> 16
```

However, you don't need to let the array take care of this. In ActiveRecord's case, it could easily let the converted array respond to `count`, but by defining that method internally, the SQL query can be constructed in a more efficient way. Calling different methods on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` changes the state of the object, and that state ultimately determines what query pops out when it's time to retrieve the data.

Let's also expand the `Query` API to respond to Ruby's explicit and implicit array conversion methods:

```
class Query
  def to_a
    execute
  end

  def to_ary
    to_a
  end
end
```

So now, `to_a`, `to_ary`, and `execute` all do the same thing, but those two extra methods give us several advantages. First of all, the explicit array conversion method (`to_a`) conforms to the conventions already in place in the Ruby's core and standard library. We could actually just rename `execute` to `to_a`, as it's not necessary to have both.

`to_ary`, though, gives us something different. It lets us treat a query object as if it were implicitly an array, so if we try to add it to another array, or call the `Array()` conversion method on it, it behaves as expected:

```
my_array = [1,2,3]
q = Query.new.where(->(x){ x > 95 })

my_array + q # => [1,2,3,96,97,98,99,100]
```

Again, `execute` was never explicitly called, but the `to_ary` method defines what should happen when you try to concatenate an array with a non-array object like `Query`. What we've done is create an "array-like" object.

Comment: Thank you for a very thoughtful and thorough answer. I've learned inject, among other things!

Comment: Did you mean @database.numbers.send instead of execute.send?

Comment: I am still confused though. In your example, there is a method `execute`. ActiveRecords somehow manages without. How? By overriding the assignment operator perhaps?

Comment: Right. If you'll notice in the `map` example, I never actually called `execute` - the Query instance did that implicitly. Regarding your other question, since `map` is an array (enumerable) method, we want to call that on the result of execute (the filtered set of numbers from the db). Calling it on `database.numbers` would give us more than we asked for.

Comment: I added a few more examples to the answer showing implicit conversions.

Comment: Wow, a dynamic language with implicit conversions - that hurts my head! Though, on the second thought, I don't see why not. BTW, an unrelated question: given an object, how do you find out its type?

Comment: `object.class` returns the class of an object, and `obj.is_a?(Array)` will return a boolean value if the given class is part of the object's ancestor chain. However, in practice, it's generally considered better design to use implicit conversions or duck typing rather than asking about class of objects and switching based on the result.

Answer (score 4):

In one word: laziness. Postpone building SQL query (and accumulate information, like calls to `where`, `sort` or `count`) until you try to fetch actual data. By that time you will know what exactly you need to fetch and will be able to construct an efficient query.